# No module named antlr4 in python 2.7

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

I would like to use ANTLR4 with Python 2.7 and for this I did the following:

1. I installed the package `antlr4-4.6-1` on Arch Linux with `sudo pacman -S antlr4`.
2. I wrote a `MyGrammar.g4` file and successfully generated Lexer and Parser Code with `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 MyGrammar.g4`
3. Now executing for example the generated Lexer code with `python2 MyGrammarLexer.py` results in the error `ImportError: No module named antlr4`.

What could to be the problem? FYI: I have both Python2 and Python3 installed - I don't know if that might cause any trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install `antlr4` for python through `pip`:

```
sudo pip install antlr4-python2-runtime
```

If you don't have `pip` on you system, install it first with:

```
sudo pacman -S python2-pip
```

Comment: I tried this but sadly it did not work. After executing the pip install command it says `Requirement already satisfied: antlr4-python2-runtime in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. It might be the case that pip does not work correctly for the two python versions but I don't know how to figure out the problem...

Comment: I just copied the antlr4 files from `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and this solved the problem!

Comment: @ec-m Maybe you could try `sudo pip2 install antlr4-python2-runtime`, because this would call `pip` for Python2.

Comment: Oh, perfect! I didn't know that this is possible. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `antlr4` was only installed for Python3 and not Python2. I simply copied the antlr4 files from `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and this solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip install antlr4-python2-runtime
```

or:

```
python -m pip install antlr4-python2-runtime
```