# ANTLR4 python syntax error with setup example

Tags: python, antlr4

Trying to setup ANTLR for python following this instructions
  http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2016/03/15/antlr-python.html

and additionally using a local copy of antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar

there are syntax errors.

With python2 this:

```
> from antlr4 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/antlr4/__init__.py", 
line     1, in <module>
    from antlr4.Token import Token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/antlr4/Token.py", line 59
    def text(self, text:str):
                       ^
```

With python3 this:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_Hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from antlr4 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4/__init__.py", 
   line     5, in <module>
    from antlr4.BufferedTokenStream import TokenStream
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4    
    /BufferedTokenStream.py", line 18, in <module>
    from antlr4.error.Errors import IllegalStateException
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4/error/Errors.py",     
    line 39, in <module>
    from antlr4.Recognizer import Recognizer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4/Recognizer.py", line    
    6, in <module>
    from __builtin__ import unicode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

To generate the python code I used a fresh copy of Antlr4 - Version 4.7.1 - jar in the working directory 
and generated the python files for python2 like this:

```
alias antlr4='java -jar antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar'
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Hello.g4
```

and

```
alias antlr4='java -jar antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar'
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 Hello.g4
```

for python3.

Python 2 version is 2.7.15+
Python 3 version is 3.6.8.

I already had a look at some similar question, like this:
  [Python+ANTLR4: No module named antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737716/pythonantlr4-no-module-named-antlr4)

but could  not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: 1)isnt that builtinS , 2)and this is imported iny py3 by default? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047745/where-is-the-builtin-module-in-python3-why-was-it-renamed

Comment: changed "import __builtin__" to "import buildins".
Next error is: "cannot import name 'unicode'".
Maybe I should ask: "why are there such compatibility problems at all?"

Comment: I took a look at the files in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/antlr4.
It seems, that most of the include files have variable - type definitions in function defs like this:
def create(self, source, type:int, text:str, channel:int, start:int, stop:int, line:int, column:int):
Is that python 2.7  - compatible at all?
(e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489669/function-parameter-types-in-python)

Comment: no, its python 3 some last version feature. Install latest python for that

Comment: I understand. But the libraries are installed to be included with python2.7.
With python 3 there is another problem (please see the error messages in the question). So it seems, that the code installed with pip is neither compatible with python2 nor python3.

Comment: ahahahaha)))) seems in antlr text:str is incompatibel for python 2 and No module named '__builtin__' for python 3 they must be kidding, man you must edit antlr :DD delete the line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'  cause builtins are imported by default

Comment: Thanks. Did you delete this line? Did antlr4 work then?

Comment: i did pip install antlr4-python3-runtime and i gont no errors.

Comment: O.k.: I just commented out the "import builtin"-line. This seems to work
with python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my solution by using:

1. python 3.7.6
2. pip 22.1.2
3. antlr4-python3-runtime 4.9

This answer comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65054963/10987905).